# deliver_later with Sidekiq causes 500 error when unable to connect to Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq

In one of my Rails application controllers, I do something like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)

  # send welcome email
  UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliver_later
end
```

Now, I've intentionally disabled my Redis server so that I can replicate what would happen in the case that a connection couldn't be made from my app.

Unfortunately, this entire `create` request fails with a 500 if the `deliver_later` is unable to connect to Redis.

What I'd like is that the request still succeeds, but the mailer fails silently.

How can I accomplish this?

**Additional information:**

In config/initializers/action_mailer.rb:

```
  rescue_from(Redis::CannotConnectError) do |exception|
      Rails.logger.error "Original record not found: #{@serialized_arguments.join(', ')}"
  end
```

This never gets called though on exception. I tried `rescue_from(StandardError)` and `(Exception)`, but that was never called either.

I'm using sidekiq as my job queue adapter:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

The 500 error I get is:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
```

My `UserMailer` is a subclass of `ApplicationMailer` which is a subclass of `ActionMailer::Base`.

Comment: Why don't you simply rescue the exception?

Comment: @user3033467 where? I have deliver_later code all over the app, so want to do it from one single place.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to catch that error globally without monkeypatching or introducing a facade.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent calls to `deliver_later` from crashing when Redis is down, we added the following monkey-patch:

```
# If +raise_delivery_errors+ is false, errors occurring while attempting to
# enqueue the email for delivery will be ignored (for instance, if Redis is
# unreachable). In these cases, the email will never be delivered.
module MessageDeliveryWithSilentQueueingErrors
  def deliver_later
    super
  rescue Redis::CannotConnectError => e
    raise if raise_delivery_errors
    # Log details of the failed email here
  end

  def deliver_later!
    super
  rescue Redis::CannotConnectError => e
    raise if raise_delivery_errors
    # Log details of the failed email here
  end
end

ActionMailer::MessageDelivery.send(:prepend, MessageDeliveryWithSilentQueueingErrors)
```

Comment: What file did you put this in? What version of rails was this for? Having the exact same issue and wondering if I can still use this for my current Rails 5.2 project or if y'all ended up refactoring it.

Comment: @Zachary this would have been for Rails 4.2.x (I left before we made the jump to 5). We keep all these monkey-patches in `config/initializers/`, so this was probably `config/initializers/message_delivery_with_silent_queueing_errors.rb` No clue if it still works in 5.x, but it's worth a shot!